# how to store data into h2 database which is loaded from my localDB for caching purpose. SO that i can use simple queries to fetch data

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have huge data in my DB. Everytime hitting DB will impact performace. So i want to call findall method on some of the tables and store that in h2 database so that i can use h2 database whenever i need to fetch data. I saw ehcache and inmemory caching techniques. but none helped me. This is to use simple queries to fetch data.

I used @caching annotations. And able to get data from cache. But while filerting with specific values, i have to use streams. which decreasing code readability.

PLease help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a findAll and then filtering it out is not good for the performance of your application. And if your DB is large, you can use Elasticsearch for RD operations. They are much faster and you can limit the fields you want to fetch, which will boost your performance further.
Anyway, using the h2 database is not going to boost your performance if your data is huge.